# How do I interpret the behavior of COBOL missing end-ifs

Tags: cobol, microfocus, procobol

I am trying to understand the behavior of some COBOL code that seems to be missing end-if statements in the nested if statements. Could someone please explain, if you can? I marked where I think there should be end-if statements I believe are missing. However, I do not want to alter this code without understanding how it would fall through the if statement nest.

```cobol
       040-EACH-RENDITION.
           READ TC298-PAYFILE AT END
             MOVE 'Y' TO END-INPUT
           .
           IF END_INPUT = 'Y' THEN
              CONTINUE
           ELSE           
              MOVE SPACES TO HOLD-CO-CODE;
              MOVE PF-ACCOUNT TO HOLD-PF-ACCOUNT;
              EXEC SQL
                 SELECT COUNTY-CODE
                   INTO HOLD-CO-CODE
                   FROM TAXDTL
                  WHERE CLIENT-ID = :ACT-CLIENT-ID
                    AND CAN = :HOLD-PF-ACCOUNT
                    AND YEAR = :CLIENT-CURRENT-YEAR
              END-EXEC
              IF HOLD-CO-CODE = SPACES
                 MOVE 'XXX' TO HOLD-CO-CODE
              END-IF;
              DISPLAY 'AFTER SELECT HOLD-CO-CODE=' HOLD-CO-CODE ';'
                      PF-ACCOUNT
              MOVE RENDITION-BEGIN-DATE TO RENDITION-FIX-DATE
              IF PF-LEVY = 0
                 CONTINUE
              ELSE
                 IF PF-YEAR < RENDITION-BEGIN-YEAR
                    IF (ACT-CLIENT-ID = 81000000
                       AND PF-YEAR = 2005
                       AND PF-DEPOSIT-DATE < '20080309')
                       CONTINUE
                    ELSE
                       IF (ACT-CLIENT-ID = 81000000
                          AND PF-YEAR = 2006
                          AND PF-DEPOSIT-DATE < '20080301')
                          CONTINUE
                       ELSE
                          IF PF-DEPOSIT-DATE < RENDITION-BEGIN-DATE
                             CONTINUE
                          ELSE
                             MOVE PF-ACCOUNT TO RP-CAN
                             MOVE PF-YEAR TO RP-YEAR
                             MOVE PF-JURISDICTION TO RP-TAXUNIT
                             MOVE PF-RECTYPE TO RP-RECTYPE
                             MOVE PF-OWNERNO TO RP-OWNERNO
                             MOVE PF-RECEIPT TO RP-RECEIPT
                             MOVE PF-VALNUM TO RP-VALNUM
                             MOVE PF-REMIT-SEQ TO RP-REMIT-SEQ
                             MOVE PF-DEPOSIT TO RP-DEPOSIT
                             PERFORM 042-GET-PENALTY
                             IF RENDITION-SW = 'Y'
                                MOVE PF-RECORD TO WF-RECORD
                                MOVE RENPEN-AMOUNT TO WF-RENPEN
                                MOVE HOLD-CO-CODE TO WF-COCODE
                                WRITE WF-RECORD
                             END-IF
      *   seems a few missing end-if statements should go here
                 ELSE 
                    MOVE PF-ACCOUNT TO RP-CAN
                    MOVE PF-YEAR TO RP-YEAR
                    MOVE PF-JURISDICTION TO RP-TAXUNIT
                    MOVE PF-RECTYPE TO RP-RECTYPE
                    MOVE PF-OWNERNO TO RP-OWNERNO
                    MOVE PF-RECEIPT TO RP-RECEIPT
                    MOVE PF-VALNUM TO RP-VALNUM
                    MOVE PF-REMIT-SEQ TO RP-REMIT-SEQ
                    MOVE PF-DEPOSIT TO RP-DEPOSIT
                    PERFORM 042-GET-PENALTY
                    IF RENDITION-SW = 'Y'
                       MOVE PF-RECORD TO WF-RECORD
                       MOVE RENPEN-AMOUNT TO WF-RENPEN
                       MOVE HOLD-CO-CODE TO WF-COCODE
                       WRITE WF-RECORD
           .
       042-GET-PENALTY.
```

Comment: I'm afraid this piece of code actually works as intended and as indented. The last `ELSE` will be matched to the last `IF` that didn't have an `ELSE` and/or `END-IF. And the full stop before `042-GET-PENALTY` will end it all. Not recommend though.

Comment: The fact that `END-IF` is optional is apparent in the syntax diagram in [the documentation](https://www.microfocus.com/documentation/visual-cobol/vc90/DevHub/HRLHLHPDF90A.html).

Answer (score 2):

Like mentioned in the comments, an ELSE statement will be paired with the last IF statement without an ELSE.

I personally detest this type of code because it is hard to verify as working correctly.  I hate counting END-IF's and ELSES.  I prefer to rework that type of code to use an EVALUATE TRUE statement with multiple WHEN clauses.